# Dynamic programming algorithm to find a colorful subset of disjoint sets

Tags: parameterized-complexity, fixed-parameter-tractable, dynamic-programming

> Suppose there is a set $F=\{X_1 ,...,X_m\}$, such that $\forall 1\leq
>   i\leq m: |X_i|=3.$ Suppose we color the elements of $\bigcup F$ in
> $3k$ colors. We wish to know if there is a subset $F'\subseteq F$ such
> that all sets in $F'$ are pairwise disjoint, and $F'$ is colorful,
> i.e. $\bigcup F'$ uses all $3k$ colors.

I'm trying to come up with a parameterized fixed tractable dynamic programming algorithm for the task, but I had a couple of issues.

First I thought of defining $M[C,i]$ to be $true$ iff there is a solution subset of $F$ with respect to $C$ and $i$, that is, it only uses $\{X_1,...,X_i\}$ and all the colors in $C$.

But when trying to define the recursive relation, if we set $I=\{j < i: X_j \cap X_i = \emptyset  \} $, then $M[C,i]= M[C\setminus col(X_i), I]\vee M[C,i-1]$ which doesn't make much sense since $i$ is a number and $I$ is a set, but still I cannot allow selection of a colorful set using $\{X_1 ,... , X_{i-1}\}$ since it might not be disjoint of $X_i$ even though it is pairwise disjoint within itself.

Any ideas on a better definition or a fix for this definition?
(Using subsets of $1,...m$ is not an option since that would mean $\Omega(2^m)$ entries which is not FPT)

Comment: Note that we can assume $|F'| \le 3k$, so we can use the color coding technique on the elements of $\cup F$, coloring them with $9k$ random colors, and requiring that in $\cup F'$ all elements have different colors. This has FPT success probability and can be solved by DP in FPT time.

Comment: why $9k$ colors instead of $3k$? And the problem is actually how to solve this by DP?

Comment: Sounds like an exercise instead of a research-level question in theoretical computer science.

Comment: @Laakeri That's what I was asking for help with. The DP part...